# Add headers to fetch and XHR requests when using whatwg-fetch polyfill

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest, fetch, polyfills

Hy, everyone.

I'm using a fetch polyfill called [whatwg-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch) on an ReactJS application that uses both `fetch` and `XHR`. The problem is that I need to add a token on every request (fetch and XHR).

I could simply create a polyfill to fetch requests:

```
window.fetch = function(url, options) {
   // ...
   options.headers['token'] = token
   return window.fetch.apply(this, [options])
}
```

and XHR requests:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
   // ...
   this.setRequestHeader('token', token)
}
```

But this approach can add two tokens, making the application to not work properly. This happens in polyfilled environments, where **whatwg-fetch** simulates a fetch using XHR, making the XHR to be called after a `fetch`.

I wasn't able to find a way to check the XHR header. Apparently there is a `setRequestHeader`, but not a `getRequestHeader`.

There is a way to indentify if the XHR is called by the window.fetch polyfill, or any idea to solve this? Any idea would help :)